# textView.setLines(int lines) not working for textview.

Tags: android, textview, android-adapter

I have ListView Adapter and the textview setLines is not working.

inside the method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

I have this code:

```
    holder.title.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            int lineCount    = holder.title.getLineCount();

            LogUtils.log("LINE_NUMBERS: " + lineCount+"");

            if(lineCount == 2){
                descriptionLineAmount = 6;
                holder.description.setLines(descriptionLineAmount);
            } else {
                descriptionLineAmount = 4;
                holder.description.setLines(descriptionLineAmount);
            }
        }
    });
```

The description line number is not changing (the cells are not updating with extra rows).

Comment: Do you have any additional attributes in your XML?

Comment: maxlines 2 for title and description has lines set to 4.

Answer (score 0):

write this inside of onclick :
     ViewHolder tagHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

and then instead of holder use tagHolder